# Hibernate: how to fetch only not-logically deleted objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, soft-delete, mappedsuperclass

Nearly every table in our database has a FK to the Auditing table which logs created, updated and deleted status (date and username).

We mapped the auditing table to the Auditing class and use it like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BusinessObject extends DataObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1147811010395941150L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUD_ID")
    private AuditingObject auditing;
...
```

As you'd expect, nearly every entity extends from BusinessObject.

Is there an easy way of saying, for every businessObject, only receive "auditing.deleted is null".

I've tried adding a @Where and @WhereJoinTable in the businessObject but this doesn't seem to work as I expect.

Currently, i've done this to one of my queries and this works, but I'd hate to do this for all queries since we have about 150.

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="allCountries",
    query="SELECT c FROM Country c"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH c.labelDefinition "
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH c.labelDefinition.translations "
        + " WHERE c.auditing.deleted is null"
        + " ORDER BY c.code"
)
```

Answer (score 12):

IMO, the easiest way to implement a soft-delete would be to add a flag in your entities and to use:

- the [`@SQLDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-customsql) annotation to override the default Hibernate `delete` (and perform an update of the flag)
- the [`@Where`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-entity) (or [`@Filters`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters)?) annotation on your entities and associations to filter the deleted entities

Not sure how this can fit with your `Auditing` table though. Some further exploration and testing are required.

#### Resources

- [Soft deletes using Hibernate annotations](http://featurenotbug.com/2009/07/soft-deletes-using-hibernate-annotations/)