# Removing entries in DB by setting their status in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My team made a decision not to remove entries from database, but to give them a status like `ACTIVE` or `DELETED`.

Problem arises when, for entity - let's call it `Customer` I make a collection of another entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Order> orders;

    private MyEnumStatus status;

    ...
}
```

If I want to 'remove' one order from the list `orders` I have no influence on how is it done (especially - it will certainly not set desired status on entry in the link table and instead it will just remove a record from it).

```
@PersistenceContext 
EntityManager em;

...

Customer customer = customerService.getRandomOne();
customer.getOrders().remove(0);
em.merge(customer);
```

My question is - is it possible to apply a status field (in Order entity) to this scenario? I mean to somehow overwrite this behaviour to set statuses instead of removing entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can use either Events or Interceptors.  Both are described in [chapter 14 of the reference docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#events).  This option is powerful but hairy.  Play with it at your own risk.

Soft deletes are probably a better option. @mdatwood's link shows one way of doing this.  There's a fuller example [at feraturenotbug](http://featurenotbug.com/2009/07/soft-deletes-using-hibernate-annotations/). Don't forget to tweak all your queries return only objects that aren't deleted.  That's mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement logical deletes.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989341/1322201) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the remove() method implementation using the @SQLDelete annotation as below in your customer entity:

```
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE customer SET status = 'deleted' WHERE id = ?")
public class Customer {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Order> orders;

}
```